# Can I get older (recent) versions of Keynote?

Tags: keynote, software, versions

I have just updated Keynote to 10.0, and have noticed some loss of features.

In particular, it seems the "typewriter" animation has been replaced with "keyboard".

I recall having the option with typewriter (perhaps other animations too, I forget) to animate text by letter, so that they appeared at random. That is now gone.

Can I either retrieve that feature, or else download the 9. Keynote from before this latest update?

Any questions I have seen similar to this so far are trying to get really old versions. I just want to go back one version.

Comment: I have now found that some of the other animations do allow animation by character, which effectively solves my problem. But still, I think the question of downloading older versions will still be valuable for some others, so I'll leave it here for answers to that aspect.

Comment: There does not appear to be a simple way to get older versions of iWork applications even if they are compatible with your macOS but check out this relatively recent discussion that seem to provide some directions for installation of older versions of iWork applications including Keynote: [Old version (macOS Sierra) for Pages, Keynote and Numbers, iWork](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/376919/old-version-macos-sierra-for-pages-keynote-and-numbers-iwork)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Time Machine backup of your drive, then the previous version will be on that.

The Mac App Store will give the date of the latest update: restore a version from earlier than that.