# How can I install Pages or iWork on a Mac running High Sierra 10.13.6?

Tags: high-sierra, pages, iwork

Is there  any way now of installing a version of Pages or iWork on a Mac running High Sierra 10.13.6?

Comment: Did you try the App Store?

Comment: Yes . The current Pages won't install on High Sierra

Comment: You should include that information in your question. What you did; what the results were. All helps.

Comment: You might also report it as a bug, or question App Store support

Comment: Have you gone to the Purchases tab of the App Store?  Do you see the apps you want there?  If so, it should offer you the option to download the version for your os.

Comment: Also see. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/376919/old-version-macos-sierra-for-pages-keynote-and-numbers-iwork

Comment: You can download Pages (working for High Sierra) from: https://www.malavida.com/en/soft/pages/mac/download

Comment: You can download Numbers (working for High Sierra) from: https://www.malavida.com/en/soft/numbers/mac/

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250781090) I quote

> Actually, if you have purchased/installed Pages, Keynote, or Numbers previously, if you sign-in with your AppleID and go to the Purchased section of the App Store, you will find the application install history.  When you click on the Install button there, it will ask you if you want to download the previous version of the app that will work on non 10.14 machines.